# basis of ordered square

Tags: product-space

In ordered topology, $(a × b, a × c)$ for b < d is basis element.

so $(0 × 0.5, 0 × 2) ∩ [0,1]×[0,1] = (0 × 0.5, 0×1)$ is open in ordered square.

Is this right?

Comment: Welcome to the website, Hwang. If you are satisfied with the answers to your previous questions, it is customary to "accept" them by clicking the tick-mark button next to them. Doing so awards reputations points both to you and the answerer for taking the time out to help you. If you are not satisfied and need clarification, feel free to comment below the answers and ask for resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection is actually $S=(0\times0.5,0\times1\color{red}]$, which is infact open in the unit square with subspace topology induced by dictionary order topology in $\Bbb R^2$. But this is not open in the unit square with dictionary order topology, often called the ordered square, whose basis elements are of the form $\{[0\times0,a\times b),(a\times b,c\times d),(c\times d,1\times1]:a\times b,c\times d\in I\}$. This is because any basis element $(a\times b,c\times d)$ which contains the point $0\times1$ is not a subset of $S$.